# Gauss' law for two point charges?

Tags: electricity, electrostatic

When we model electric field as something that represents the "flow" of something that is **conserved**, we can prove that the flux due to a single point charge, through the following surface,

[Flux through a radial surface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXs8J.jpg)

is effectively zero. And therefore prove (almost) that flux through all kinds of  surfaces that do not include a charge is zero. But when we do have a charge, we perform a clever trick, we enclose the charge with another surface, in the following manner,

[Flux due to point charge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1C6b2.jpg)

and therefore prove that the flux through the required surface is equal to the flux through small surface enclosing the charge.
Therefore,

$$ \int_S \mathbf E . \mathbf {ds} = \dfrac{q}{4\pi \epsilon r^2} (4\pi r^2) \\ \int_S \mathbf E . \mathbf {ds} = \dfrac{q}{ \epsilon} 
 $$

This "trick" was possible, only because,  we had a point charge and the field was radially outward. So my question is, how are we able to generalise that the flux through any surface is equal to this fraction \$\dfrac{q}{\epsilon}\$? What if we had two point charges instead of one, then we wouldn't get a convenient \$4\pi r^2\$ term. I'm relatively new to the subject, so I'm missing something obvious. This again leads to a question; why in the first place, is there a \$4\pi\$  in Coulomb's law?

Comment: Why 4π? Just a guess, but perhaps 4π because it concerns E *and* M fields?

Answer (score 1):

The \$4\pi\$ is the number of steradians on the surface of a sphere.

If you had two points charges within the surface of integration, you could do the sums for each charge individually, and the use superposition to combine them. This of course generalises to any number of charges, and any arbitrary charge distribution, as long as it's entirely within the relevant surface.